# How to trap the error bad array subscript in Bash

Tags: bash, error-handling

This code snippet generates two errors: "command not found" that is trapped by trap and "bad array subscript" that is not. Is there a way to trap "bad array subscript?"

Running Bash version 4.4

```
shopt -s extdebug  # Necessary after 4.3 for trapping in functions
set -o pipefail
set -o errtrace

error() {
    echo "There was an error at line $1"
}
trap 'error ${LINENO}' ERR

declare -A arr
foo=''
# Next line generates one error:
# -bash: arr: bad array subscript  # this error is not trapped
"${arr[$foo]-echo}"

# Next line generates two errors:
# -bash: arr: bad array subscript  # this error is not trapped
# -bash: : command not found  # this error is trapped
"${arr[$foo]}"
:
```

Comment: I would think not. Without getting too technical (read: I can't explain it properly), the bad-subscript error is a *parse* error outside the scope of the execution, while the command-not-found error is an execution error *within* the scope of the execution. `trap` handles the latter kind, not the former.